# Pine-script SECURITY function doesn't return consistent result

Tags: pine-script

In order to backtest one of the strategy, I need to retrieve day HIGH value for last 5 days and this should work under any chart resolution.

Below code works fine when the chart resolution is DAILY, but if I change the chart resolution to a lower timeframe  i.e. 15mins or 30 mins I get same day high values for Day-2,3,4 & 5.

Ideally, Security functions output should not be impacted by change in chart resolution and output should be distinct values.

```
// @version=4
study("Plot high prices for lat 5 days")

day_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high, false)
day1 = day_high[1]
day2 = day_high[2]
day3 = day_high[3]
day4 = day_high[4]
day5 = day_high[5]

//Check whether this is the first bar of the day? If yes, display highs for last 5 days
t = time("1440", session.regular)
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

if (is_first)  
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(day5) + ", " + tostring(day4) + ", " + tostring(day3) + ", " + tostring(day2) + ", " + tostring(day1), style=label.style_cross, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `security()` function for each of your variables.

You can read [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) for more details.

```
// @version=4
study("Plot high prices for lat 5 days")

day1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
day2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[2], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
day3 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[3], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
day4 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[4], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
day5 = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[5], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Check whether this is the first bar of the day? If yes, display highs for last 5 days
t = time("1440", session.regular)
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

if (is_first)  
    label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(day5) + ", " + tostring(day4) + ", " + tostring(day3) + ", " + tostring(day2) + ", " + tostring(day1), style=label.style_cross, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

[image]

Comment: Since I need to call security function for each of the variable, is there a way to store the value of these variables into an array?

Comment: There is no arrays in `pinescript`.